# How do I move the previous commit to the head of the branch

Tags: git, github

I'm working on a project with a collaborator and neither of us are really good at GitHub. The project is [here](https://github.com/sjkiss/CES_Analysis/tree/blais_replication). He has pushed a [commit](https://github.com/sjkiss/CES_Analysis/commit/7b1aee3b338496d117eb1c2499b33e7c078761b2) that I basically don't want. I want *my* [commit](https://github.com/sjkiss/CES_Analysis/commit/b8b0907bc259f245ff039805179b943763ddb5d9) to be the head. Apparently there are some conflicts in two files, and I can't even figure out where they are.
I have tried 
`git reset --hard b8b0907bc259f245ff039805179b943763ddb5d9`

and that did revert my local repository to be the commit that I wanted. But it wouldn't let me push that because it said my local branch was behind:

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

Comment: With changes such these, when you reset to some commit and want the same to be on `origin`, you have to `force` push the changes. Basically saying "My branch is in state it should be for everyone". The only issue is that peole who have the up-to-date master have to reset their local branch to the one on `origin`

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you're asking for:

```sh
git stash                                # in case you have any unsaved changes
git fetch                                # update your local repo with what's in remote origin
git checkout blais_replication           # move HEAD to this branch
git reset --hard b8b0907bc259f2          # set branch to that commit (7b1aee is now "lost")
git push --force                         # make remote origin like how your repo is
```

Note this will effectively "change history" by making it as if `7b1aee` was never committed. Other users will see a sync issue because of the history change. They can run:

```sh
git checkout blais_replication
git fetch                                   # update local repo
git reset --hard origin/blais_replication   # moves branch to where origin/blais_replication has been moved back to (b8b0907bc259f2)
```